# Rounding all columns excep first one - power query

Tags: rounding, powerquery

I have question - is that possible to use for rounding all columns except first one? 
I use some clue from changing data types from Alexis Olson (thank you it is veeeery usefull), but I cannot add to this syntax rounding. 
When using syntax

`= Table.TransformColumns(
      #"Rename column",
      List.Transform(
          List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Rename"),1),
      each Number.Round(_, 0))
  )`

appears - Expression.Error: Value "2019_1" cannot be transferred to type Number - for explain 2019_1 is header value.

Can anybody help me, please?
Thank you very much in advance
Jiri

Comment: Could you pls provide a sample?

Comment: Is #"Rename column" and #"Rename" the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
round = Table.TransformColumns(Source,List.Transform(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
                                                     each {_, Number.Round}))
```

`Number.Round` here is equivalent to `Number.Round(_,0)`.

P.S. I usually use 3rd argument of Number.Round (rounding mode), for instance, if you wish to round 0.5 to 1: `Number.Round(_, 0, 2)`

Comment: Perfect, simple, elegant, effective - thank you very much Aleksei :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should return a list of lists, where first element is a column name and second - a *function* that is applied to value. But not list of functions only

```
let
  Source = #table({"first", "second", "third", "fourth"},{
    {  1,   2,   3,   4},
    {1.1, 2.2, 3.7, 4.9}
  }),
  cols = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
  cols_1 = List.RemoveFirstN(cols, 1),
  transformation_list = List.Transform(cols_1, (column_name)=>{column_name, (value)=>Number.Round(value, 0)}),
  round = Table.TransformColumns(Source, transformation_list)
in
  round
```

So `transformation_list` is

[image]